# Tensorfow, много npy файлов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, tensorflow, deeplearning4j

У меня есть 20 npy файлов входных shape=(n,64,64,24) и 20 файлов выходных shape=(n,64,64,12).
Как мне с помощью fit или fit_generator либо чего-либо ещё пропустить их всех через сеть tensorflow?
Не могу их объединить по причине того что мне не хватает оперативной памяти.

Comment: А сколько у вас есть оперативной памяти?

Comment: 16 gb и GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.
В сумме я уже решил проблему через fit_generator. 
Но с удовольствием почитал бы другие предложения и решения этого вопроса.

Comment: Отлично! Вы можете написать ответ на собственный вопрос, чтобы помочь другим участникам :)

Answer (score 0):

```
> `x_train = glob.glob('./dataset/train/x/*.npy')
y_train = glob.glob('./dataset/train/y/*.npy')
x_test = glob.glob('./dataset/test/x/*.npy')
y_test = glob.glob('./dataset/test/y/*.npy')
def train_generator(data='train'):
    while True:
        if data=="train":
            d = zip(x_train, y_train)
        if data=="test":
            d = zip(x_test, y_test)
        for i,j in d:
            train=np.load(i)
            test = np.load(j)
            # train = create_cutted_array(train)
            # test  = create_cutted_array(test)
            # for k in range(train.shape[0]):
            a = train.reshape(1,train.shape[0],train.shape[1],train.shape[2])
            b = test.reshape(1,test.shape[0],test.shape[1],test.shape[2])
            yield (a, b)
model.fit_generator(train_generator('train'), steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_train, epochs=epoch,shuffle=False, verbose=1,               validation_data=train_generator('test'),validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_test,callbacks=[PredictionCallback(),mc])`
```